# Adding new row ID in table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 options of adding a new UNIQUE id (primary_key) to one of my particular tables.

1. Create AUTO_INCREMENT field.
2. SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
3. SELECT MAX(id) FROM table

I'm currently using option **2**, as people might delete rows from the table they access, so id's get freed, otherwise i'd be using option **1**

What do you reccommend ?

Comment: 1 without any exceptions. "so id's get freed" --- free for what? Do you have any issues with non consecutive ids?

Comment: line 1 is for creating auto ID but 2 and 3 are to select max ID, You wanna create ID or SELECT ?

Comment: Your current solution only "frees" the greatest `id` anyway... if "*people might delete rows*" with anything other than the greatest `id`, it still won't be "*freed*".

Comment: @Dev: "*I have 3 options of adding...*".  Also, question title is "*Adding new row ID in table*".

Comment: Guys, please add to your answers that #1 is the **only** thread-safe solution of 3 (and that's why it's the only acceptable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *always* use option 1 (in order to avoid the [race hazard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) of two simultaneous inserting clients reading the current maximum `id` before either has completed their insertion).  `AUTO_INCREMENT` prevents this hazard from occurring through the use of locks that make the read & write operations atomic.

Comment: thanks man...i actually wanted to minimize the max id so i would have the best usage of id as the greatness of the number....but it's true, if ppl delete rows with id lower than the greatest, it will still get max value, and add on top of it...i will use AUTO_INCREMENT from now on, it's also much safer i can see..thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Option 1

AUTO_INCREMENT

which is 
The easiest way to implement and maintain

Comment: Easiness is actually not the real reason in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Create a DB Sequence and use it instead, that will give you much more convinence even in multiple threads access scenarios and distributed environments and clustered env as well.